# Eclipse String List is not printed properly

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I'm trying to print long size String list.
but elements not printed properly.
I'm not able to figure out what's happening.

output of console :
[image]
look, head of line is not visible

but if I have slice list into 200, list printed properly.
please help me.
I'm using STS :

```
Spring Tool Suite 
Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201503100339
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)
```

code :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("testLongLongLongColumnName1",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName2", "testLongLongLongColumnName3",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName4", "testLongLongLongColumnName5",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName6", "testLongLongLongColumnName7",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName8", "testLongLongLongColumnName9",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName10", "testLongLongLongColumnName11",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName12", "testLongLongLongColumnName13",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName14", "testLongLongLongColumnName15",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName16", "testLongLongLongColumnName17",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName18", "testLongLongLongColumnName19",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName20", "testLongLongLongColumnName21",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName22", "testLongLongLongColumnName23",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName24", "testLongLongLongColumnName25",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName26", "testLongLongLongColumnName27",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName28", "testLongLongLongColumnName29",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName30", "testLongLongLongColumnName31",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName32", "testLongLongLongColumnName33",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName34", "testLongLongLongColumnName35",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName36", "testLongLongLongColumnName37",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName38", "testLongLongLongColumnName39",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName40", "testLongLongLongColumnName41",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName42", "testLongLongLongColumnName43",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName44", "testLongLongLongColumnName45",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName46", "testLongLongLongColumnName47",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName48", "testLongLongLongColumnName49",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName50", "testLongLongLongColumnName51",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName52", "testLongLongLongColumnName53",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName54", "testLongLongLongColumnName55",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName56", "testLongLongLongColumnName57",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName58", "testLongLongLongColumnName59",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName60", "testLongLongLongColumnName61",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName62", "testLongLongLongColumnName63",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName64", "testLongLongLongColumnName65",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName66", "testLongLongLongColumnName67",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName68", "testLongLongLongColumnName69",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName70", "testLongLongLongColumnName71",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName72", "testLongLongLongColumnName73",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName74", "testLongLongLongColumnName75",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName76", "testLongLongLongColumnName77",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName78", "testLongLongLongColumnName79",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName80", "testLongLongLongColumnName81",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName82", "testLongLongLongColumnName83",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName84", "testLongLongLongColumnName85",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName86", "testLongLongLongColumnName87",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName88", "testLongLongLongColumnName89",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName90", "testLongLongLongColumnName91",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName92", "testLongLongLongColumnName93",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName94", "testLongLongLongColumnName95",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName96", "testLongLongLongColumnName97",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName98", "testLongLongLongColumnName99",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName100",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName101",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName102",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName103",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName104",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName105",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName106",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName107",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName108",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName109",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName110",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName111",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName112",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName113",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName114",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName115",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName116",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName117",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName118",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName119",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName120",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName121",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName122",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName123",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName124",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName125",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName126",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName127",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName128",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName129",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName130",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName131",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName132",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName133",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName134",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName135",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName136",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName137",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName138",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName139",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName140",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName141",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName142",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName143",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName144",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName145",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName146",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName147",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName148",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName149",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName150",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName151",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName152",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName153",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName154",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName155",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName156",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName157",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName158",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName159",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName160",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName161",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName162",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName163",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName164",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName165",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName166",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName167",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName168",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName169",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName170",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName171",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName172",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName173",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName174",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName175",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName176",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName177",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName178",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName179",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName180",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName181",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName182",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName183",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName184",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName185",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName186",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName187",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName188",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName189",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName190",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName191",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName192",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName193",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName194",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName195",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName196",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName197",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName198",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName199",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName200",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName201",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName202",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName203",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName204",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName205",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName206",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName207",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName208",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName209",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName210",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName211",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName212",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName213",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName214",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName215",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName216",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName217",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName218",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName219",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName220",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName221",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName222",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName223",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName224",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName225",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName226",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName227",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName228",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName229",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName230",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName231",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName232",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName233",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName234",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName235",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName236",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName237",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName238",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName239",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName240",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName241",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName242",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName243",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName244",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName245",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName246",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName247",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName248",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName249",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName250",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName251",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName252",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName253",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName254",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName255",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName256",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName257",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName258",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName259",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName260",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName261",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName262",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName263",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName264",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName265",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName266",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName267",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName268",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName269",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName270",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName271",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName272",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName273",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName274",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName275",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName276",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName277",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName278",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName279",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName280",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName281",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName282",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName283",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName284",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName285",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName286",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName287",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName288",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName289",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName290",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName291",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName292",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName293",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName294",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName295",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName296",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName297",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName298",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName299",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName300",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName301",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName302",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName303",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName304",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName305",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName306",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName307",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName308",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName309",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName310",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName311",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName312",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName313",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName314",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName315",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName316",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName317",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName318",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName319",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName320",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName321",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName322",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName323",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName324",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName325",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName326",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName327",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName328",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName329",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName330",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName331",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName332",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName333",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName334",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName335",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName336",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName337",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName338",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName339",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName340",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName341",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName342",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName343",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName344",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName345",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName346",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName347",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName348",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName349",
                "testLongLongLongColumnName350");
        System.out.println(asList);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is just a console issue. Try to select all text in it and copy-paste it to some text editor.

Comment: I've already knew that. but I should print list out in eclipse.

Comment: Does it has to be on the one line? Is it ok if console will wrap lines?

Comment: actually, wrap lines would ok for me. If I add '\n' per several elements, it works well. or Windows > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console, check fixed with console with value 100, it would work well too. I'd like to figure out exactly reason of this bug, but I can't seem to find it.